# Comparing two associative array values that have CSV - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, associative

I have two associative arrays:

```
ArrayA = array( [10] => ten
                [12] => twelve
                [22] => 10
                [30] => 10, 12, 8
         )
ArrayB = array( [10] => net
                [12] => evlewt
                [22] => 11, 12, 10
                [30] => 10
         )
```

The values of same keys on both arrays need to be compared. Some keys have CSV values and that can be on both the arrays.

For instance, `[22]` on `ArrayA` should be checked in CSV on `ArrayB`. Likewise, `[30]` in `ArrayB` should be checked in CSV on `ArrayA`. Others should be compared as usual `==`

Note: I am trying to avoid a looping here. We can certainly do this in multiple ways with Loop. I am wondering if there is a quick and efficient way to do this without looping.

Edit: To clarify further, this is how these two should be compared:

```
Is "ten" in ArrayA == "net" in ArrayB?
Is "twelve" in ArrayA == "evlewt" in ArrayB?
Is 10 in ArrayA existing in (11, 12, 10) of ArrayB?
Is (10, 12, 8) of ArrayA containing the 10 ArrayB?
```

Comment: What are you looking for? Do you need to know if both arrays are the same? Do you need to know which array keys have the same values?

Comment: @KSiimson These two arrays are going to have SAME set of keys always. the values may change. I just want to compare the values and see if they are same. but the issue is with CSV values like I explained above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand the question correctly. If you normalize the data first you can just compare the arrays

For instance:

```
$a = array(
    10 => 'net',
    12 => 'evlewt',
    22 => '10,12,11',
    30 => '12,10'
);

$b = array(
    10 => 'net',
    12 => 'evlewt',
    22 => '11,12,10',
    30 => '12,10'
);

function normalize(&$value, $key) {
    $value = explode(',', $value);
    sort($value);
    $value = implode(',', $value);
}

array_walk($a, 'normalize');
array_walk($b, 'normalize');

var_dump($a == $b); // outputs true
```

EDIT: In order to evaluate two arrays by whether an element in either array is a subset of another, I would normalize values to array and use the `reduce_array()` function.

```
<?php
$a = array(
    10 => 'net',
    12 => 'evlew',
    22 => '10,12,11',
    30 => '12,10,11'
);

$b = array(
    10 => 'net',
    12 => 'evlewt',
    22 => '11,12,10',
    30 => '12,10'
);

function normalize(&$value, $key) {
    $value = explode(',', $value);
}

function compare_value($v, $w) {
    if (false === $v) return false;
    global $a, $b;
    if(is_subset($a[$w], $b[$w]) || is_subset($b[$w], $a[$w]))
        return true;
    return false;
}

function is_subset($needle, $haystack) {
     return count(array_intersect($needle, $haystack)) === count($needle);
}

array_walk($a, 'normalize');
array_walk($b, 'normalize');

$result = array_reduce(array_keys($a), 'compare_value', true);
var_dump($result); // outputs false

$a = array(
    10 => 'net',
    12 => 'evlewt',
    22 => '10',
    30 => '12,10,11'
);

$b = array(
    10 => 'net',
    12 => 'evlewt',
    22 => '11,12,10',
    30 => '12,10'
);

array_walk($a, 'normalize');
array_walk($b, 'normalize');

$result = array_reduce(array_keys($a), 'compare_value', true);
var_dump($result); // outputs true
```

Comment: I guess you did NOT get my question. Element 22 can have multiple values (CSV) in ArrayA, while same element in ArryB can have only one value. The value for the element 22 in ArrayB should be in CSV of the same element in ArrayA.

Comment: So if an element is CSV in ArrayA, it cannot be CSV in ArrayB, and if an element is CSV in ArrayB, it cannot be CSV in ArrayA? Or what happens if both are CSVs?

Comment: Both can be CSVs too. :-). Except this case, I guess if there is something like "IN" operator to compare the arrays, we can compare by adding some padding at the beginning and end of the each value. Like ",test,", in ",tset," and ",10," IN ",12,10,13,", etc. Not sure if anything is available. :-)

Comment: There is a function in_array($needle, $haystack). It is unclear to me what do you expect if both are CSVs. Do the CSVs have to be the same, or does left have to be subset of right, or does right have to be subset of left?

Comment: To simplify it, I just want all or ANY of the values in the 2nd array, should exist in the 1st one. So if 2nd one has CSV for an element, one of the CSV should match the value in the first one.

Comment: My question does not pertain to single values.

Comment: ONLY values should be compared. As I mentioned in the questions, both will have SAME set of keys and same number of keys. Only the values should be compared. A should contain B, in simpler terms

Comment: I've updated my answer with assumption that if two values are CSV-s, then it is OK if either of them is a subset of another.